# Should I worry about memory consumption of a 100+ module html5 app?

Tags: javascript, performance, memory, amd

Say I have an MVC-ish html5 app that consists of 100+ small modules. I'd like it to run as smooth as possible even on a tablet or a smartphone.

Since only a handful of the 100+ modules are in use simultaneously and I'd say half of them aren't even used during an ordinary session with the app, loading them as a single concatenated js file and keeping it all in memory feels kind of icky.

I currently use *CujoJS curl*, which is an AMD loader. It's great for development and I think it fits nicely in some production environments too. The downside of course is that individual files take longer to download, but I don't really consider it an issue in this case. What I'm worried about is the memory usage over time, like if the user never closes the window and more modules keep accumulating in the memory as they explore the app. As far as I know, AMD loaders don't provide any means to unload modules.

The question is, **should I really be worried about memory consumption at all in this situation?** As an exaggerated example, would the difference in memory usage between 200KiB *(on-demand essential modules)* and 4000KiB *(everything from essentials to practically never used features)* of js code be negligible even on a mobile device?

**If I should be concerned about memory consumption, what should I do to minimize wasted memory?** I can only think of minimizing the amount of code in memory by planning ahead, writing efficient code and unloading unneeded modules. Or as a last resort, by reloading the page at some points.

**Bonus question:** (How) can I unload modules from *curl* cache? I've read that in *RequireJS* it is possible with a little tweaking but I've found nothing for curl.

Comment: Do you mean runtime memory or bandwidth? Keep in mind that source files can be minified **and** gzipped.

Comment: @Halcyon I mean runtime memory. Bandwidth is a secondary concern.

Comment: Depends on how large these modules actually are. Also, even small modules can load and store large sets of data, the amount of code is rather unrelated to that.

Comment: You cannot onload any code yourself, the engine may release code if it is not used anymore(removing from curl cache may allow the engine to release it but it is not guaranteed). One thing you should keep in mind is that all current js engines do just in time compiling, because of that the memory that is used not only depends on the size of the code but also in the way it is used, the answer to the question [Should I put default values of attributes on the prototype to save space?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/28360/25332) shows one explanation why this is the case.

Comment: @t.niese so if I write an app that requires a 2MiB js file every second, the app can run indefinitely and it won't run out of memory?

Comment: @Bergi All modules in this case are treated as classes. Only the instances may store and handle data. I'm concerned about the memory required to store these classes, of which some are used vary rarely. The impact on memory usage may very well be next to nothing, but have no idea, hence this question :)

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to be large. But you can only try it out to know for sure. Load all classes, don't create any instances, make a heap snapshot.

Comment: @Bergi that's a good idea. The only problem is that I don't have those 100+ classes. What if I loaded the same file over and over again using rewrites, so the browser would see a different url for each time the file is loaded? Could it still tell the contents are the same and optimize it somehow? That would ruin the experiment.

Comment: Unlikely. Even if the same code is executed a hundred times, that would instantiate a hundred different class objects. With different script files (instead of a plain loop), there won't be any optimisations.